# How do I unit test routes in ASP.NET MVC Beta 1?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I found articles on how to unit test routes from [Stephen Walther](http://www.stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/02/asp-net-mvc-tip-13-unit-test-your-custom-routes.aspx) and from [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) in prior versions of ASP.NET MVC, but it doesn't work in ASP.NET MVC Beta 1. If I need to use a mocking framework, I'd prefer a solution that uses Rhino Mocks.

Answer (score 2):

I use Visual Studio unit tests, thats why I could not use the Helper Tim mentioned out of the box. (NUnit required). Anyway the article showed the code I needed. Actualy in the "nobody wants to use this ugly code" section.

```
        RouteCollection routes = new RouteCollection();
        MvcWeb.MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes);


        var httpContext = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();

        httpContext.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpRequestBase>());

        httpContext.Request.Stub(x => x.PathInfo).Return("");

        httpContext.Request.Stub(x => x.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Return("~/foo/bar");



        var routeData = routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);



        Assert.AreEqual(routeData.Values["controller"],"foo");
```