# How do I test UrlHelper.RouteUrl()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, controller

I'm having a tough go trying to figure out what I need to mock in my tests to show that UrlHelper.RouteUrl() is returning the right URL. It works, but I'd like to have the right test coverage. The meat of the controller method looks like this:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(ControllerContext.RequestContext);
return Json(new BasicJsonMessage { Result = true, 
   Redirect = urlHelper.RouteUrl(new { controller = "TheController", 
   action = "TheAction", 
   id = somerecordnumber }) });
```

Testing the result object is easy enough, like this:

```
var controller = new MyController();
var result = controller.DoTheNewHotness());
Assert.IsInstanceOf<JsonResult>(result);
var data = (BasicJsonMessage)result.Data;
Assert.IsTrue(data.Result);
```

result.Redirect is always null because the controller obviously doesn't know anything about the routing. What do I have to do to the controller to let it know? As I said, I know it works when I exercise the production code, but I'd like some testing assurance. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I feel your pain.  There is no good way to verify your calls to RouteUrl will produce the desired result short of an integration test.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you're trying to test some of your own code that invokes a UrlHelper rather than testing the functionality of the framework's UrlHelper itself.  If that is the case, this answer [ASP.NET MVC: Unit testing controllers that use UrlHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674458/asp-net-mvc-unit-testing-controllers-that-use-urlhelper) has worked great for me.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `UrlHelper.RouteUrl()` a framework method? That's the .NET team's responsibility to test, not yours!

What you might want to do is to unit test your **route configuration**. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494993/how-do-i-unit-test-routes-in-asp-net-mvc-beta1) is really old (MVC Beta 1), but the answer might still be valid. And [Phil Haack](http://www.haacked.com/)'s [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) is always there for you. If that's not enough, there are tons of other options on Google.

Comment: In this case, I'm not testing the framework code as much as I want to test that the framework code is getting the right data from me. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jeff, It does, in a way, but it would seem you're doing one step too much. Have you checked out the fluent route tester? http://flux88.com/blog/fluent-route-testing-in-asp-net-mvc/